# Unity: Why wont my movement return to value 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi im new to programming in C# and i ran  into  a problem.Eveything is working,only the value wont return to 0 when the button is not pressed,i can change the direction of the movement,but the object wont stop moving...Here is the code!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb2D;
    private float speed = 1f;
    private float moveHorizontal;

    void Start()
    {
         rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }
  
    void Update()
    {
         moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (moveHorizontal > 0.1f || moveHorizontal < -0.1f)
        {
            rb2D.AddForce(new Vector2 (moveHorizontal * speed, 0f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you adding forces, but you never reset the velocity to `0` anywhere

you could do this like e.g.

```
if(Mathf.Abs(moveHorizontal) > 0.1f)
{
    ...
}
else 
{ 
    var vel = rb2D.velocity; 
    vel.x = 0; 
    rb2D.velocity = vel; 
}
```